# AS3 video loop doesn't work on Mac OS

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, video

For reasons too complicated to explain here, I've suddenly had to start making Flash ads with AS3.

I'm a designer, I know little enough about coding languages and have to tinker with found code to make things work. So I've tried to make a simple flash ad with a looping video, which works fine on windows machines, but not on Mac ones (the video plays once, doesn't loop).
Any idea what is wrong with my very simple code ?

```
var fl_NC:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
fl_NC.connect(null);    

var fl_NS:NetStream = new NetStream(fl_NC);
fl_NS.client = {};

var fl_Vid:Video = new Video( 300, 600 );
fl_Vid.attachNetStream(fl_NS);
addChild(fl_Vid);

var theVid = "http://www.glenat.com/dyn/glenat/upload/flv/grand angle_VE4.mp4";

fl_NS.play(theVid);

fl_NS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, NCListener); 
function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){ 
  if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") { 
    fl_NS.play(theVid); 
  } 
}
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd verify that you're actually receiving the buffer empty event on Mac OS.  If you are, and it's still not working, try [ns.seek(0)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#seek()).

**Update:**

[`play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play()) should really be renamed `load()` as it's purpose is to read from a file.  `seek()` will move the playhead back to the time index you specify, so `0` would put it at the beginning.

By adding the `trace(e)` at the beginning of your function, you'll know if your function is being called, and what type of data it received.

Try replacing `NCListener` with the following...

```
function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent) {
    trace(e);
    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") {
        fl_NS.play(theVid);
        fl_NS.seek(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not sure how to do that, but I'll investigate in this direction.

Comment: Updated with some further info.  Hopefully this explains what I meant sufficiently.